# Mongoose or regex query

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, mongoose

I am trying to build a mongoose search query that searches for different fields that start and end with the search term, however I still get [] as a result.

**data.csv**

```
bookID,title,authors,average_rating,isbn,isbn13,language_code,  num_pages,ratings_count,text_reviews_count,publication_date,publisher,
1,Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (Harry Potter  #6),J.K. Rowling/Mary GrandPré,4.57,439785960,9.78044E+12,eng,652,2095690,27591,9/16/06,Scholastic Inc.,
2,Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (Harry Potter  #5),J.K. Rowling/Mary GrandPré,4.49,439358078,9.78044E+12,eng,870,2153167,29221,9/1/04,Scholastic Inc.,
4,Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (Harry Potter  #2),J.K. Rowling,4.42,439554896,9.78044E+12,eng,352,6333,244,11/1/03,Scholastic,
5,Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (Harry Potter  #3),J.K. Rowling/Mary GrandPré,4.56,043965548X,9.78044E+12,eng,435,2339585,36325,5/1/04,Scholastic Inc.,
8,Harry Potter Boxed Set  Books 1-5 (Harry Potter  #1-5),J.K. Rowling/Mary GrandPré,4.78,439682584,9.78044E+12,eng,2690,41428,164,9/13/04,Scholastic,
9,"Unauthorized Harry Potter Book Seven News: ""Half-Blood Prince"" Analysis and Speculation",W. Frederick Zimmerman,3.74,976540606,9.78098E+12,en-US,152,19,1,4/26/05,Nimble Books,
10,Harry Potter Collection (Harry Potter  #1-6),J.K. Rowling,4.73,439827604,9.78044E+12,eng,3342,28242,808,9/12/05,Scholastic,
12,The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide: Five Complete Novels and One Story (Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy  #1-5),Douglas Adams,4.38,517226952,9.78052E+12,eng,815,3628,254,11/1/05,Gramercy Books,
13,The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy (Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy  #1-5),Douglas Adams,4.38,345453743,9.78035E+12,eng,815,249558,4080,4/30/02,Del Rey Books,
```

```
Book.find({$or: [
    { title: {$regex : "^" + req.params.search + "^"} },
    { authors: {$regex : "^" + req.params.search + "^"} },
    { publisher: {$regex : "^" + req.params.search + "^"} },
    { language_code: {$regex : "^" + req.params.search + "^"} }
  ]}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err', err)
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log('result', result)
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes are wrong. You need to use `$` to indicate the end.

```
    { title: {$regex : "^" + req.params.search + "$"} },
    ...
```

Comment: I still get [] as a response

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? (data and search term)

Comment: I've added data to my question... you can try searching for harry

Comment: well, then I think you don't actually mean "fields that start and end", but "start OR end". Can that be?